# Aligning underset below matrix equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, matrices, subscripts

I wonder how I can align undersets below equations of matrix.
I tried underset and stack under for the scripts, and tried vphantom for aligning. Your help will be much appreciated!

I need the below equation: [image]

But instead, I have this:[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\begin{equation}

\begin{equation}
\underset{\pmb{y}\in \mathbb{R}^m}{\begin{bmatrix}
18\\5\\15\\-9\\-3\\
\end{bmatrix}}= 
\underset{\pmb{A}\in \mathbb{R}^m\times n}{\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{\pmb{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n}{\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 3\\ -2\\ -5\\ 1\\ 4
\end{bmatrix}}

\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), **with preamble**. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simple ... just add a `\vphantom` of the height of the tallest matrix to the other two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    

\begin{equation}
\underset{\pmb{y}\in \mathbb{R}^m}{%
\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{bmatrix}
18\\5\\15\\-9\\-3\\
\end{bmatrix}}= 
\underset{\pmb{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}}{%
\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}
\underset{\pmb{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n}{\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 3\\ -2\\ -5\\ 1\\ 4
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

a couple of comments: 
 - don't leave blank lines inside of *any* math; this will always result in an error. 
 - i removed an extra `\begin{equation}` from the provided example.

Comment: It should be `\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}`; also `\pmb` leads to bad output and `\bm` should be used instead.

Comment: @egreg -- to paraphrase @egreg, "i just used what was provided by the op."  (but i agree that using `\bm` is much to be preferred.  i fixed the superscript.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the comments. I was giving an integer to \vphantom, I’m new..

Comment: @kneazle -- you can let us know which answer you found most useful by clicking on the check mark that appears by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}}
\begin{bmatrix}
18\\5\\15\\-9\\-3\\
\end{bmatrix}
&{}={}&
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 3\\ -2\\ -5\\ 1\\ 4
\end{bmatrix}
\\[1ex]
\mathclap{\scriptstyle\bm{y}\in \mathbb{R}^m} &&
\mathclap{\scriptstyle\bm{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}} &
\mathclap{\scriptstyle\bm{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that it should be `\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}` and that you should use `\bm` rather than `\pmb`.

[image]